# SendKeys(Keys.Tab) does not work on Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116

Tags: tabs, key, sendkeys

Today I observed that SendKeys(Keys.Tab) does not working on Chrome webdriver. However it works perfectly on IE and FireFox. Other than Tab, i tried few other keys like Space, Backspace, Clear, some text, Enter etc working as expected on Chrome.

for example:
           private IWebDriver driver;
           private string baseURL;

```
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?");
       driver.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName")).Clear();
       driver.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName")).SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

Anybody know why, Keys.Tab won't working on latest Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116?

OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1

The cursor suppose to move/focus to Last name text field

Comment: We experienced similar issues and found that it does work on v52.  Not a solution, but a potential work around.

Comment: This issue been solved/fixed on latest Chrome webdriver v2.24. http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/

Answer (score 0):

try to add code below at the end of your code:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName"));
if (!element.Equals(driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement())) return;
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].blur();", element);
```

It means if the cursor still focus on current element, trigger blur function to move to next element.